# Why does my balls velocity eventually stop decreasing when applying gravity?

Tags: java, velocity, gravity

When applying gravity to my ball objects velocity at first it acts as intended, accelerating while falling, having friction half the velocity and then reversing the velocity. The problem is eventually the velocity seems to get to a point where it stops decreasing and the ball starts to slightly jump up and down on the floor.

The code bellow represents my process for applying gravity to the balls.

```
double y        = 100;
double vel      = -10;
double gravity  = -1;
double friction = 0.5;

while(true) {
    y += vel;

    //if collides with floor
    if(y < 0) {
        y = 0;
        vel *= -1;
        vel *= friction;
    }

    else
        vel += gravity;
}
```

In this particular example the velocity eventually starts to bounce back and forth from -1.3333... 0.666... and -0.333...

My goal is for the ball to bounce against the floor, having its velocity decreased with each bounce, until it eventually reaches a velocity of 0 and rests against the floor.

Comment: Why wouldn't it move up? You're code multiplies the velocity by -1 (i.e. reversing direction) when the ball is touching the floor.

Comment: Probably because it never ends up exactly at y=0. You need to compensate for the fact that your floor may not be at the exact edge of your time step. And if it is, you are letting the ball keep moving through it. Check `y <= 0` instead of `y < 0`.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist With `<=`, the OP will encounter the strange land of equality comparison of floating point values. To avoid that, they can use `>` and switch the `if` and `else` clauses.

Comment: You should set some thresholds. Imagine your ball is moving ever so slowly, it is then passing y by a fraction of a unit, but then immediate the velocity is increased by the gravity, even though in fact it is so close to the floor, it wouldn't have time to accumulate all this acceleration. You should set the condition so that if y<0 and also the velocity is very small, they are both set to 0.

Comment: Better yet, you should make a more accurate calculation for your else clause - the accumulated velocity should depend on the distance to the floor (based on basic physics

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. Not really, if you do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem in the code... after certain bounces.. the max height of the ball goes beyond the previous maximum height. This clearly violates Physics. Just like you put a `y<0` check to avoid letting `y` go to the negative side, you should put a `y>prevMaxY` to not allow the height go beyond the previous max.

```
else if(y > maxY) {
    y = maxY;
    vel *= -1;
    vel *= friction;
}
```

For this, you have to keep track of the previous maximum height.

Also, as the terminating condition, you should put a threshold on `y` which would mean - `if max height is less than the threshold then the ball has come to rest`.

Your approximations/assumptions are pretty crude, though. You might consider refining them.

Answer (score 0):

Logging helps understand the weird oscillations.

Start with this (which is where it gets to after about 65 frames):

```
vel: -1.365234375 
y: 0.26953125
```

The next frame, the ball hits the floor and vel is flipped and halved:

```
vel: 0.6826171875 
y: 0
```

Next, ball moves up and vel switches to negative:

```
vel: -0.3173828125 
y: 0.6826171875
```

Next, the ball moves down and vel decreases some more:

```
vel: -1.3173828125 
y: 0.365234375
```

Next, the ball hits the floor, and vel is halved and flipped again:

```
vel: 0.65869140625 
y: 0
```

Notice that we're now very close to where we started, and it will continue this way, normalizing down to about y = 1/3 and y = 2/3.

If you remove the effect of gravity from the else statement and allow gravity to affect every frame, the ball will settle at zero.

Example in p5js: https://editor.p5js.org/bcingle/sketches/hfVbE9YJf